# Get all the COMMITS from all the repositories of an organization in Github using R

Tags: r, api, github, get

Hey so I am using this line in R:

```
request <- GET("https://<host-name>/api/v3/search/commits?=org:<org-Name>",
                add_headers(Authorization= "token <token number>",
 Accept= 'application/vnd.github.cloak-preview'))
```

And I get this as a result:

```
]
  Date: 2019-03-21 09:13
  Status: 422
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
  Size: 221 B
{
  "message": "Validation Failed",
  "errors": [
    {
      "resource": "Search",
      "field": "q",
      "code": "missing"
    }
  ],
  "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/enterprise/2...
...
```

It says that code is missing
In the get request I have to syntax a query where I pass the org name as "q" parameter but what is this code that it says its missing?

Comment: `?=org:` looks suspicious, query parameters have a `key=value` syntax.

Comment: I saw it here: https://help.github.com/en/articles/searching-commits
It says Qualifier can be. org: ORGNAME

Comment: That would be part of the *value* for the query parameter `q`, and the colon should be URL-escaped. See the example from those docs: [`https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=test+org%3Agithub&type=Commits`](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=test+org%3Agithub&type=Commits).

Comment: yeah but how can I syntax it in R? to get all the commits from all the repositories for my sepecific organization.

Comment: ...`?q=org%3A<org-Name>`?

Comment: I found a solution check my answer. The ?q=org% works for a url but not for a Get request.

Comment: What do you *mean*? Entering that URL in your browser *makes* a GET request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

Basically in front of `commits?` should've been `commits?q=` but that also didn't work because it requires a string field so: `commits?q=stringfield+org:{org-name}`

```
request <- GET("https://<host-name>/api/v3/search/commits?=org:<org-Name>",
                add_headers(Authorization= "token <token number>",
 Accept= 'application/vnd.github.cloak-preview'))
```

Comment: Also the snippet you've posted doesn't match what you describe. By "string field" do you mean the actual search term?

Comment: Yeah looks like you cant search for commits without a string. A search term yeah. Like a single word. But now I am finding it hard to use a string that will give me all the commits for sure. Because thats what I want. All the commits of all the repositories.

Comment: Why are you using the search API at all, then? If you want all commits from all repos in an org, you probably want to hit https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-organization-repositories then the `commits_url ` https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/#list-commits-on-a-repository

Comment: Thats for regular API. I am using enterprise edition api which has other documentation.

Comment: I think those are *extra* endpoints for the enterprise version, it still exposes the rest of the same API the hosted version does.

Comment: I'm saying that it doesn't seem like the most sensible fit for the task you seem to be trying to accomplish.

Comment: It is the only way to get from organization/repos/commits. Do you have any other way? That I can do that?